# Finding Fourier Transform for $f_m(t) = f(mt)$ in terms of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, fourier-analysis

Let $F_{CD,T}$ be the continuous discrete Fourier Transform on T-periodic functions:

$F_{CD,T}(f)(nT^{-1}) = \int_0^T f(t)e^{\frac{-2\pi i n t}{T}}dt$ , $n\in \Bbb{Z}$

Suppose we have the function $f_m(t)=f(mt)$ for any $m \ne 0 \in \Bbb{Z}$. Compute $F_{C,D,1/m}(f_m)$ in terms of $F_{C,D,1}(f)$ and use this to compute $F_{C,D,1}(f_m)$.

---

My attempt:

$F_{C,D,1/m}(f_m(mt))(nm) = \int_0^{\frac{1}{m}}f(mt)e^{\frac{-2\pi i n mt}{1/m}}dt = \int_0^{\frac{1}{m}}f(mt)e^{-2\pi i n m^2t}dt$. On the other hand,

$F_{C,D,1}(f(t))(n) = \int_0^{1}f(t)e^{2\pi i nt}dt$

I'm not quite sure where to go from here to write the first expression in terms of the second.